# OneSignal blocked with uBlock / AdBlocker

Tags: onesignal

I'm implementing OneSignal, but I noticed it's being blocked if a user has uBlock and/or AdBlocker chrome plugins active. Is there any way to use an iframe or a way to trigger the subscribe programmatically?
This seems to be a deal breaker so far...

Answer (score 0):

I see several options here:

1. put the OneSignalSDK files on your hosting storage (for example AWS S3 bucket) and load from there. Will suffer on updates.
2. Configure nginx (if using it) to proxy a subdomain under your domain to the external destination, like [here](https://serverfault.com/a/922461/237269). Or here's and [example](https://github.com/verificatorrus/onesignal-proxy) with CloudFlare, but you may find other I am sure.

Second option actually is the only one, since the SDK js uses same cdn.onesignal.com URLs underneath, the 1st option wouldn't work. But an alternative is to ask a user to allow requests to this CDN.